# Cookie will not change expiration date

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cookies, web

I'm trying to delete all the cookies that my site uses but from reading I can't do that so I believe my only option is to change the expiration date to be in the past and let the browser do the work. I have one cookie at the moment called 'CookieDisplay'. On the page load event in asp.net I have :

```
  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    For Each key As String In Request.Cookies.AllKeys
        Dim cookie As New HttpCookie(key)
        If (Not Request.Cookies(cookie.Name.ToString) Is Nothing) Then

            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1D)
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

This code finds the cookie for 'CookieDisplay' and changes the expiration date. However on the client side I have javascript that triggers after the page load event with the following.

```
  function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}

function checkCookie() {


        var SavedData = getCookie("CookieDisplay");
    if (SavedData != null && SavedData == "true") {
        closeme();
    }
}
```

The problem is the cookie is returning a value so the expiration date hasn't taken affect so the cookie doesn't expire and therefore still shows. Could it be because this cookie gets created in javascript and asp.net doesn't have access to this? Do I have to expire the cookies from javascript and asp.net depending on where the cookie got created?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookie created by Javascript and Cookie created by HTTP request do not differ. Check the domains and paths, these cookies are set for. They should be the same.

Comment: I have added cookie.Domain = "localhost" to the server side code as the original cookie (created by javascript) has put the domain as localhost. This has made no difference.

Comment: Can you add the javascript setCookie function to your question?

Comment: function acceptClicked()
             {
                setCookie("CookieDisplay", true, 365);
                
              }

Comment: Sorry not sure how to add code in the comment box. anyway if the above is called. it runs this function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) { var exdate = new Date(); exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays); var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString()); document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value; }

Comment: You are able to edit your question... check, that cookie paths are also the same

Comment: I think you're getting closer, I've matched the path and in firefox this is working however in internet explorer 8, the cookie doesn't change.

Comment: For some reason the cookie.location was causing the problem and that coupled with cookie.path not being added in caused the updated cookie to be ignored. The reason it was only working in some browsers and not other is because the  cookie paths are different for example in IE it is "/CookieTest/" and in Chrome it is"/CookieTest". I used Request.Browser.Browser = "AppleMAC-Safari" to get around this.The only odd thing is that chrome and safari bring back the same browser name but not a problem for me as they bring back the same cookie path.

Comment: I think I read somewhere that the is due to outdated config file in the .net framework folder but I could be wrong. Anyway thanks for pointing me in the right direction.